# How to pipe across lines?

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a script, which includes a line like this:

`curl example.com | grep "some words | xargs mkdir | ad --nauseum`

My question is, can I break that into multiple lines while still redirecting the output (or is there a better pattern for this scenario?)

Comment: With a backslash just before the newline, last character of each line. This must have been asked before - I'm searching for complete answers.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: only C shells require backslashes after the pipes.  Real shells (those based on Bourne shells) do not require backslashes, and (IMNSHO) sea shells are best left on the sea shore (and the requirement for backslashes is one reason for thinking that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One interesting fact of pipe notation is that it will accept newlines (and formatting white space) without problems:

```
curl example.com   | 
grep "some words"  | 
xargs mkdir        | 
ad --nauseum
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean just splitting your code line in to multiple ones, you can just use 
`\` symbol, like

```
curl example.com \
| grep "some words \
| xargs mkdir \
| ad --nauseum
```

By this you'll just escape new line and your script will act like a one-liner still

Comment: This was a good contender for best answer.  Arguably more readable, but I accepted @BinaryZebra's answer due to elegance/simplicity.

Comment: Icky notation.  There's no point in using two symbols (backslash and pipe) where one will do (pipe — as long as it is on the end of the line).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yep, that was something new to me. But I'll still stuck to mine since it gives unified code for me in both piped long lines and the ones without them. Just the habit for myself - splitting a line: put backslash